# Accessing a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, cell-array

I have a cell array **A** who's  dimensions is in multiples of 8. For ex **1x192**  , now i want to pick the elements of the cell array in the following way.

**1,9,17,25...nth** elements should be  stored it in a separate cell array. similarly **2,10,18,26...n** in a separate cell array and another set would be 3,11,19,27 in a separate cell array. this must be continued till **8,16,24,32..n**

How can i automate this, where the cell array size is dynamic. But it is always a multiple of 8.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: use the `end` keyword `A(1:8:end)`, `A(2:8:end)`, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing would be `reshape`: since the cell array's length is always divisible by 8, you can reshape it to be 8 rows tall. Each row then is one of your separate cell arrays:

```
>> c = num2cell(1:192);

>> c8 = reshape(c(:), 8, [])
c8 =
  8x24 cell array
  Columns 1 through 9
    {[1]}    {[ 9]}    {[17]}    {[25]}    {[33]}    {[41]}    {[49]}    {[57]}    {[65]}
    {[2]}    {[10]}    {[18]}    {[26]}    {[34]}    {[42]}    {[50]}    {[58]}    {[66]}
    {[3]}    {[11]}    {[19]}    {[27]}    {[35]}    {[43]}    {[51]}    {[59]}    {[67]}
    {[4]}    {[12]}    {[20]}    {[28]}    {[36]}    {[44]}    {[52]}    {[60]}    {[68]}
    {[5]}    {[13]}    {[21]}    {[29]}    {[37]}    {[45]}    {[53]}    {[61]}    {[69]}
    {[6]}    {[14]}    {[22]}    {[30]}    {[38]}    {[46]}    {[54]}    {[62]}    {[70]}
    {[7]}    {[15]}    {[23]}    {[31]}    {[39]}    {[47]}    {[55]}    {[63]}    {[71]}
    {[8]}    {[16]}    {[24]}    {[32]}    {[40]}    {[48]}    {[56]}    {[64]}    {[72]}
  Columns 10 through 18
    {[73]}    {[81]}    {[89]}    {[ 97]}    {[105]}    {[113]}    {[121]}    {[129]}    {[137]}
    {[74]}    {[82]}    {[90]}    {[ 98]}    {[106]}    {[114]}    {[122]}    {[130]}    {[138]}
    {[75]}    {[83]}    {[91]}    {[ 99]}    {[107]}    {[115]}    {[123]}    {[131]}    {[139]}
    {[76]}    {[84]}    {[92]}    {[100]}    {[108]}    {[116]}    {[124]}    {[132]}    {[140]}
    {[77]}    {[85]}    {[93]}    {[101]}    {[109]}    {[117]}    {[125]}    {[133]}    {[141]}
    {[78]}    {[86]}    {[94]}    {[102]}    {[110]}    {[118]}    {[126]}    {[134]}    {[142]}
    {[79]}    {[87]}    {[95]}    {[103]}    {[111]}    {[119]}    {[127]}    {[135]}    {[143]}
    {[80]}    {[88]}    {[96]}    {[104]}    {[112]}    {[120]}    {[128]}    {[136]}    {[144]}
  Columns 19 through 24
    {[145]}    {[153]}    {[161]}    {[169]}    {[177]}    {[185]}
    {[146]}    {[154]}    {[162]}    {[170]}    {[178]}    {[186]}
    {[147]}    {[155]}    {[163]}    {[171]}    {[179]}    {[187]}
    {[148]}    {[156]}    {[164]}    {[172]}    {[180]}    {[188]}
    {[149]}    {[157]}    {[165]}    {[173]}    {[181]}    {[189]}
    {[150]}    {[158]}    {[166]}    {[174]}    {[182]}    {[190]}
    {[151]}    {[159]}    {[167]}    {[175]}    {[183]}    {[191]}
    {[152]}    {[160]}    {[168]}    {[176]}    {[184]}    {[192]}

>> c8(4,:)
ans =
  1x24 cell array
  Columns 1 through 9
    {[4]}    {[12]}    {[20]}    {[28]}    {[36]}    {[44]}    {[52]}    {[60]}    {[68]}
  Columns 10 through 18
    {[76]}    {[84]}    {[92]}    {[100]}    {[108]}    {[116]}    {[124]}    {[132]}    {[140]}
  Columns 19 through 24
    {[148]}    {[156]}    {[164]}    {[172]}    {[180]}    {[188]}
```

Comment: That was a great use of Reshape function, Thank you @Ahmed Fasih :)